# c++ dynamic array names

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I would like to be able to change the name of the array I am referring to when printing it. I would like to change "placeholder" from current to moves. I want current to be editable, but once switched to moves, I'd like it to lock its value. Is there any way I could accomplish this or a better way for what I am trying to do? It is for a stupid tic tac toe game in which you use wasd to move a cursor (asterisk), and k to mark your position (x). I know how to do the "ai" but am stuck on this. Thanks!

```
*| | 
-----
 | | 
-----
 | |


x| | 
-----
 | | 
-----
 | |


char current[3][3] {{' ', ' ', ' '}, { ' ', ' ', ' ' }, { ' ', ' ', ' ' }};
char moves[3][3] {{' ', ' ', ' '}, { ' ', ' ', ' ' }, { ' ', ' ', ' ' }};

void printBoard(){
    system("cls");
    cout << placeholder[0][2] << '|' << placeholder[1][2] << '|' << placeholder[2][2] << '\n';
    cout << "-----\n";
    cout << placeholder[0][1] << '|' << placeholder[1][1] << '|' << placeholder[2][1] << '\n';
    cout << "-----\n";
    cout << placeholder[0][0] << '|' << placeholder[1][0] << '|' << placeholder[2][0] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Please guys this is just a noob trying to learn. Give him some advises, not just downvotes without caring at all about the question, just for being rather basic.

Comment: Don't worry, there's a lot of people here who usually forget that nobody is born with all knowledge, and there was a time when they where learning too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the array you want to print as parameter:

```
void printBoard(const char (&array[3][3]))
{
    cout << array[0][2] << '|' << array[1][2] << '|' << array[2][2] 
    ...
}

printBoard(current);
printBoard(moves);
```

*Also you might improve your code with `for` loops to print the arrays.*

Comment: sorry to bother you again, you don't have to answer, but would you mind explaining why this works?

Comment: This is not a good place to discuss topics in depth, but to answer specific questions. I suggest you to get a good C++ book to learn the basics. Check the C++ tag, it contains a list of recommended books.